# Export too large issue in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, classification, pixel, random-forest

Here is the path to my script- https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/?accept_repo=users%2Fujavalgandhi%2FEnd-to-End-GEE&scriptPath=users%2FchakrabortySoumik95%2Ffirstprogram%3Asentinel%20Australia%2C%20South%20east%20asia%20(China%20%2B%20Aus%20%2B%20SE)%20(copy)

I am trying to get a classified output using random forest classifier for Victoria province of Australia. First I have trained the classifier and then deriving output. The problem comes when I try to export the result to drive for some reasons it asks for this value "8030040147504"as Max pixels and it takes hours to even get the data rendered or getting it exported to drive.

I have tried doing the entire process using a very small portion getting it clipped and the final export still asks for this number "8030040147504" of pixels and takes huge time.

What is the issue here? Is there some fault at GEE server because I have repeated the process a week before and it was working perfectly with max pixel value of "1e11". The "vic_100" represents a small portion of the province but still it is showing a lot of pixels, although I require the output for the entire victoria province at once.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: vic_100,
    description: 'vic_100',
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'vic_100',
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e11
});
```

or

```
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: vic_100,
    description: 'vic_100',
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'vic_100',
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 8030040147504
});
```

Comment: Try to specify the `region` property.

Comment: @DanielWiell why is the region important?

Comment: If you're sure the area you're interested should contain fewer than your `8030040147504` pixels at 10m scale, you must be including pixels outside of that area. The `region` property specifies the region to export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: vic_image,
    description: 'vic_image',
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'vic_image',
    region: grid_no,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e11
  });
```

The region needed to be specified.